# Qt qmake and DISTFILES

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

So I am learning to program in OpenGL 3.3 and I am using qtcreator as my IDE with qmake as the compiler. Everything is fine except I have to read 2 files (fragmentshader.frag and vertexshader.vert) using ifstream. 
I have included those 2 files in the ".pro" like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
shaders.cpp

LIBS += -lGLEW -lglfw -lGL -lX11 -lpthread -lXrandr -lXi

DISTFILES += \
vertexshader.vert \
fragmentshader.frag

HEADERS += \
shaders.h
```

and in the code I try to directly read "vertexshader.vert" and "fragmentshader.frag".

My question is: How do I include these files in my application without having to specify an absolute path?

Comment: Make sure these files are reachable from application's working directory, then use relative path?

Comment: You could use Qt resource system: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: The thing is if I place the 2 files in the executable file's directory it works but I would like to include these file directly in the executable. I know qt ressource system but I'm only using qt as an IDE I don't want to use their API for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, it comes from the fact Qt is running files from another directory (by default from the build one).

### The Fix

So you have two options:

- change the *Working directory* in *Projects->Build & Run->Run* to `%{sourceDir}`.
- change the *Build directory* in *Projects->Build & Run->Build* to `.` or leave it blank.

### Explanations

- The *first option* run your program (.exe on Windows) from the sourceDir, where your project sits, so path will remain the same relatively.
- The *second option* place all your build files (ie: Makefile, *.o and ".exe") in your project directory (they won't appear in the project view unless your *Add* them), I prefer this way because now your project directory contains everything related to it.

Choose the one you prefer the most, hope it helps.